# How to get case insensitive cmis:folder search query

Tags: cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

stmt = session.createQueryStatement("SELECT * FROM cmis:folder WHERE IN_TREE(?) and cmis:name=?");
                         stmt.setString(1,'sites/test/documentLibrary');
                         stmt.setString(2,'Test');

I got result with exact folder name(Test) case senstive, but If i gave  foldername test or TEST result not found.

Could you please help me on case insenstive folder search.

Answer (score 2):

The CMIS QL does not support case insensitive queries because many repositories can't provide it.

Depending on the repository and the repository setup, a LIKE query might be case insensitive.

Btw. `IN_TREE` takes a folder ID, not a folder path.