# CMIS query case insensitive

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I'm using CMIS query to fetch documents from Alfresco. I found one big problem. Apparently CMIS doesn't support case insensitive searches. I also tried AFTS and Lucene but they're inconsistent (can't fetch a just saved document). Are there any workarounds for Alfresco to construct a case insensitive query?

Comment: Have you read and understood https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/solr-event-consistency.html ? It may not actually be possible to do what you want for just-added files with search

Comment: CMIS does not support case-insensitive searches, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248608/how-to-get-case-insensitive-cmisfolder-search-query